# "Unable to find the apex source" when running test in Winter 16' version

Tags: eclipse, git, apex

I have this error message: "Unable to find the apex source" after running a test in the Winter 16' version of Apex in Eclipse, when the project is located in a Git depository. I mean that the test runs. Even shows, at the end, coverage results but there is no System Debug Log information, neither User Debug Log information and instead of writing the name of the class next to the "green V" signaling that the test passed, nothing is written and when I click on it, I have this error message.

Note that when the project is simply in the Eclipse workspace (not in a Git depository), there is no problem, and there is also System Debug Log and User Debug Log information.

I've tried to configure the test running configuration, but with no success.

Is there anyone who knows how to handle that?